# IsWrapped property of MessageContractAttribute is missing in Mono

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a problem with generated proxy class in wcf. I noticed the MessageContract is wrapped in my soap message, but i need to remove it. Unfortunatly, I can not resolve IsWrapped property of MessageContract attribute.

(I would like to add service reference to my portable library, using MVVMCross)
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750528.aspx

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)] //Cannot resolve symbol 'IsWrapped' (default value is true and i cannot change it)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is not possible from within a PCL assembly, because the WCF implementation is not cross platform and available in PCL libraries. I have used the `IsWrapped` property to be implemented in the MonoTouch projects. I have no experience with MonoDroid and WCF.